# How to pass post request parameters dynamically to get request in Karate

Tags: javascript, api, automation, cucumber, karate

How do I pass a value of one API attribute to another API while automating in [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate)? I have a POST request which when submitted will generate an id in the response, and I pass that id dynamically to the upcoming GET request. 
I have already tried writing an Java method to read and write but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE] of your Java method that doesn't work so we can better help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please forget about Java for a moment, Karate is very different !

For you I suggest you do this. Use the ZIP Release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

There is a ready-made test `users.feature`. See how line 12 extracts the first array element from the response and then we need to use the `id` key out of that element (which is a JSON object).

And then on line 14, it is used to make the next request.

[image]

Please spend some time reading [the documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate), it is worth it !

Comment: Thanks for response I can refer the document again and let u know the reason I have added is explained below with detailed example. Let's say I have an url as given below http://hhddhkraj.intranet.xdomain.com/web/api/v2/USER-ID-374/accounts/view hope to pass the variable - USER-ID-374 as variable to the url I have tried adding below approach but it didn't worked

Comment: Thanks for response I can refer the document again and let u know the reason I have added is explained below with detailed example. Let's say I have an url as given below http://hhddhkraj.intranet.xdomain.com/web/api/v2/USER-ID-374/accounts/view      hope to pass the variable - USER-ID-374 as variable to the url I have tried adding below approach but it didn't worked.                         
 * def urlvariable USER-ID-374                  Given path 'http://hhddhkraj.intranet.xdomain.com/web/api/v2/' + urlvariable + '/accounts/view'